# uWSGI xml/ini config options

Tags: xml, configuration, uwsgi

Is there any description for all the processed tags in the xml/ini config for uWSGI?
The docs say that all the command line options may go in xml/ini, but there is more, in particular the following config is processed properly:

```
<uwsgi>                                                  
    <home>/var/www/example.com/</home>                   
    <pythonpath>/var/www/example.com/app</pythonpath>
    <app mountpoint="/">                                 
        <script>example</script>                         
    </app>                                               
</uwsgi>
```

In this snippet there is the `app` tag, that contains the nested `script` tag. But none of them is a command line parameter for uwsgi.

Is there a complete list for this kind of tags? Are these options applicable to the ini configs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the command like options are available to xml/ini/yaml file and ldap.

`<app>` Is the only exception: it is available only in xml

uwsgi --help

for the full list

Answer (score 1):

I too would like to see a full descriptive list of XML options.
I guess you've pretty much just as me has searched through the entire net without any consistent results either.

The best approach I guess is to just sooth through the related source code and try to make something out of it I'm afraid.